# Is it worth re-editing when a reviewer's "reject and edit" fails to fix problems that you fixed?

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

I recently [suggested this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5760271) to a question, fixing grammar, spelling, formatting, and clarifying the title.

[image]

A reviewer declined the edit with "reject and edit," though they removed many of my changes and (imo) made some of the grammar worse

[image]

Is it worth re-editing to clean up the title/formatting again? Should I wait for someone with full edit privileges to do so?

Comment: I just edited to fix this up, but IMO it's worth re-suggesting the edit. You probably will get new reviewers... and fixing everything in an edit is important.

Comment: I'm sorry your suggestion was rejected; it was good and I do not understand the reviewer's reasoning for rejecting it. I have @-notified her in a comment on the question directing her to this Meta post.

Comment: @larissa I'm really sorry about this but the title looked different to me and I didn't able to understand and next time I will keep that in mind and please don't mind. I'm really sorry!

Comment: @MaryMelody If you don't understand a particular edit in the review queue, hit the "Skip" button!

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot yea, you're right but probably you know that you need 2000 reputation points to review suggested edits and my reputation points was 2009 points when I reviewed her suggestion and that was my first day and instead of **improve edit** I selected the **reject and edit** option and **made some of the grammar worse** but believe me larissa this is not what I was trying to do, all I wanted was to keep the original title but I was not able to do that. I'm sorry and Good Luck! :)

Comment: @MaryMelody it's fine, I'm not cross about the edit, I was curious what the procedure was in cases like this to avoid edit wars. Good luck with future reviewing!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you feel like your edits were *widely* better than the final result, then yes, go ahead and suggest the edits again. But if your edits were *sligthly* better then let it go and go ahead with another task. Always bear in mind that this kind of things just happens: you do your best editing a post and somebody screws it up making it worse.

It happened to me that after spent some time editing a poor question, a couple of minutes later the OP just overwrote my edits making the question even worse than before. Also my answer (which took me a while too) stopped making sense. Being new to Stack Exchange I posted this case on [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195903/how-proceed-when-op-overrides-my-edits) and surprisingly to me the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195904) I got made me feel better:

> *There are well over 5 million questions on the site. We all try to make every question as good as possible, but sometimes the OP doesn't
>   cooperate. In that case, I'd respect the OP's decision to delete my
>   edits. After all, it's only 0.00002% of all the questions on the
>   site.*

I think the same principle applies here too: if you did your best and someone did not appreciate enough, then turn the page and go ahead editing another answer or asking/answering a question or whatever you like to do in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Always best to use comments after your first edit is overwritten/rejected.  Otherwise you are engaging in an edit war.  You tried to help, if they don't accept that help you have other mechanisms to address the issue:

- Down Voting
- Close vote (Only if a reason applies to the currently question's text, don't just close vote cause you don't like their grammar.  If you can figure out unambiguously what they are trying to say then a close vote probably isn't appropriate.)
- If severe enough issue, you can flag for moderation.  This is probably only appropriate if they are trying to vandalize a previously answered question, or posting links to malware.  I.e. it is something that needs immediate attention or a moderator to override the question.

In most other situations the community close/voting mechanisms make the problem go away, and the asker will realize they need to think twice about ignoring edits/comments.  If it doesn't, then it probably isn't that severe of a problem and the community majority is able to understand what is being asked.